# Find files created at same date and move into another folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have many video files, shot at the same time on 2 different cameras and copied into folders 1 and 2.

I'm looking to iterate through files in folder 1, select the newest file, and iterate through folder 2 and find the file with the same timestamp, and copy both those files into a new folder, i.e. copy files from directory camera 1, camera 2 to new directories named pair 1, pair 2, pair 3, pair 4 etc etc

Is there a simple way of writing a batch script that will do the above for me in a Windows command?

Something like this:

```
SET COUNT 0

for %%i in ("1/*.mp4") do (
SET FILE1=%%i
SET DATE1=%%~ti


 for %%a in ("2/*.mp4") do (

    SET FILE2=%%a
    SET DATE2=%%~ta
    IF "%DATE1%"=="%DATE2%" (
    COUNT ++
    make dir "scene_"%COUNT%
    MOVE 1/%FILE1% "scene_"%COUNT%
    MOVE 2/%FILE2% "scene_"%COUNT%

    )


)
)
```

But my Windows scripting isn't up to much so I doubt this will work.

EDIT thanks

If I leave echo in, I get

> MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0078.mp4" "scene_8\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0361.mp4" "scene_9\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0079.mp4" "scene_9\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0361.mp4" "scene_10\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0080.mp4" "scene_10\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0362.mp4" "scene_11\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0080.mp4" "scene_11\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0362.mp4" "scene_12\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0081.mp4" "scene_12\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0362.mp4" "scene_13\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0082.mp4" "scene_13\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0362.mp4" "scene_14\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0083.mp4" "scene_14\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0363.mp4" "scene_15\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0080.mp4" "scene_15\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0363.mp4" "scene_16\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0081.mp4" "scene_16\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0363.mp4" "scene_17\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0082.mp4" "scene_17\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0363.mp4" "scene_18\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0083.mp4" "scene_18\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0364.mp4" "scene_19\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0081.mp4" "scene_19\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0364.mp4" "scene_20\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0082.mp4" "scene_20\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0364.mp4" "scene_21\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0083.mp4" "scene_21\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0365.mp4" "scene_22\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0083.mp4" "scene_22\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0365.mp4" "scene_23\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0084.mp4" "scene_23\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0365.mp4" "scene_24\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0085.mp4" "scene_24\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0366.mp4" "scene_25\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0084.mp4" "scene_25\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0366.mp4" "scene_26\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0085.mp4" "scene_26\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0367.mp4" "scene_27\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0084.mp4" "scene_27\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0367.mp4" "scene_28\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0085.mp4" "scene_28\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0370.mp4" "scene_29\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0086.mp4" "scene_29\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0370.mp4" "scene_30\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0087.mp4" "scene_30\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0370.mp4" "scene_31\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0088.mp4" "scene_31\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0370.mp4" "scene_32\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0089.mp4" "scene_32\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0370.mp4" "scene_33\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0090.mp4" "scene_33\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0371.mp4" "scene_34\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0086.mp4" "scene_34\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0371.mp4" "scene_35\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0087.mp4" "scene_35\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0371.mp4" "scene_36\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0088.mp4" "scene_36\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0371.mp4" "scene_37\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0089.mp4" "scene_37\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0371.mp4" "scene_38\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0090.mp4" "scene_38\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0372.mp4" "scene_39\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0086.mp4" "scene_39\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0372.mp4" "scene_40\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0087.mp4" "scene_40\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0372.mp4" "scene_41\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0088.mp4" "scene_41\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0372.mp4" "scene_42\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0089.mp4" "scene_42\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0372.mp4" "scene_43\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0090.mp4" "scene_43\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0373.mp4" "scene_44\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0086.mp4" "scene_44\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0373.mp4" "scene_45\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0087.mp4" "scene_45\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0373.mp4" "scene_46\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0088.mp4" "scene_46\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0373.mp4" "scene_47\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0089.mp4" "scene_47\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0373.mp4" "scene_48\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0090.mp4" "scene_48\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0374.mp4" "scene_49\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0088.mp4" "scene_49\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0374.mp4" "scene_50\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0089.mp4" "scene_50\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0374.mp4" "scene_51\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0090.mp4" "scene_51\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0375.mp4" "scene_52\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0091.mp4" "scene_52\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0375.mp4" "scene_53\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0092.mp4" "scene_53\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0376.mp4" "scene_54\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0091.mp4" "scene_54\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0376.mp4" "scene_55\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0092.mp4" "scene_55\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0377.mp4" "scene_56\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0093.mp4" "scene_56\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0377.mp4" "scene_57\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0094.mp4" "scene_57\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0377.mp4" "scene_58\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0095.mp4" "scene_58\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0377.mp4" "scene_59\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0096.mp4" "scene_59\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0378.mp4" "scene_60\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0093.mp4" "scene_60\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0378.mp4" "scene_61\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0094.mp4" "scene_61\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0378.mp4" "scene_62\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0095.mp4" "scene_62\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0378.mp4" "scene_63\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0096.mp4" "scene_63\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0379.mp4" "scene_64\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0094.mp4" "scene_64\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0379.mp4" "scene_65\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0095.mp4" "scene_65\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0379.mp4" "scene_66\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0096.mp4" "scene_66\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0380.mp4" "scene_67\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0095.mp4" "scene_67\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0380.mp4" "scene_68\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0096.mp4" "scene_68\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0381.mp4" "scene_69\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0098.mp4" "scene_69\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0381.mp4" "scene_70\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0099.mp4" "scene_70\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0381.mp4" "scene_71\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0100.mp4" "scene_71\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0381.mp4" "scene_72\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0101.mp4" "scene_72\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0381.mp4" "scene_73\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0102.mp4" "scene_73\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0382.mp4" "scene_74\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0098.mp4" "scene_74\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0382.mp4" "scene_75\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0099.mp4" "scene_75\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0382.mp4" "scene_76\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0100.mp4" "scene_76\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0382.mp4" "scene_77\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0101.mp4" "scene_77\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0382.mp4" "scene_78\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0102.mp4" "scene_78\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0383.mp4" "scene_79\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0098.mp4" "scene_79\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0383.mp4" "scene_80\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0099.mp4" "scene_80\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0383.mp4" "scene_81\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0100.mp4" "scene_81\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0383.mp4" "scene_82\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0101.mp4" "scene_82\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0383.mp4" "scene_83\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0102.mp4" "scene_83\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0384.mp4" "scene_84\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0099.mp4" "scene_84\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0384.mp4" "scene_85\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0100.mp4" "scene_85\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0384.mp4" "scene_86\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0101.mp4" "scene_86\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0384.mp4" "scene_87\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0102.mp4" "scene_87\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0384.mp4" "scene_88\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0103.mp4" "scene_88\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0384.mp4" "scene_89\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0104.mp4" "scene_89\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0385.mp4" "scene_90\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0102.mp4" "scene_90\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0385.mp4" "scene_91\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0103.mp4" "scene_91\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0385.mp4" "scene_92\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0104.mp4" "scene_92\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0386.mp4" "scene_93\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0102.mp4" "scene_93\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0386.mp4" "scene_94\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0103.mp4" "scene_94\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0386.mp4" "scene_95\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0104.mp4" "scene_95\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0387.mp4" "scene_96\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0102.mp4" "scene_96\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0387.mp4" "scene_97\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0103.mp4" "scene_97\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0387.mp4" "scene_98\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0104.mp4" "scene_98\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0388.mp4" "scene_99\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0106.mp4" "scene_99\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0388.mp4" "scene_100\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0107.mp4" "scene_100\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0388.mp4" "scene_101\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0108.mp4" "scene_101\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0388.mp4" "scene_102\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0109.mp4" "scene_102\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0389.mp4" "scene_103\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0106.mp4" "scene_103\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0389.mp4" "scene_104\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0107.mp4" "scene_104\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0389.mp4" "scene_105\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0108.mp4" "scene_105\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0389.mp4" "scene_106\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0109.mp4" "scene_106\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0389.mp4" "scene_107\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0110.mp4" "scene_107\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0390.mp4" "scene_108\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0107.mp4" "scene_108\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0390.mp4" "scene_109\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0108.mp4" "scene_109\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0390.mp4" "scene_110\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0109.mp4" "scene_110\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0390.mp4" "scene_111\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0110.mp4" "scene_111\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0391.mp4" "scene_112\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0109.mp4" "scene_112\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0391.mp4" "scene_113\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0110.mp4" "scene_113\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0391.mp4" "scene_114\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0111.mp4" "scene_114\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0392.mp4" "scene_115\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0109.mp4" "scene_115\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0392.mp4" "scene_116\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0110.mp4" "scene_116\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0392.mp4" "scene_117\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0111.mp4" "scene_117\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0392.mp4" "scene_118\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0112.mp4" "scene_118\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0392.mp4" "scene_119\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0113.mp4" "scene_119\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0393.mp4" "scene_120\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0111.mp4" "scene_120\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0393.mp4" "scene_121\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0112.mp4" "scene_121\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0393.mp4" "scene_122\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0113.mp4" "scene_122\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0393.mp4" "scene_123\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0114.mp4" "scene_123\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0393.mp4" "scene_124\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0115.mp4" "scene_124\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0394.mp4" "scene_125\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0111.mp4" "scene_125\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0394.mp4" "scene_126\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0112.mp4" "scene_126\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0394.mp4" "scene_127\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0113.mp4" "scene_127\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0394.mp4" "scene_128\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0114.mp4" "scene_128\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0394.mp4" "scene_129\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0115.mp4" "scene_129\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0395.mp4" "scene_130\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0111.mp4" "scene_130\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0395.mp4" "scene_131\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0112.mp4" "scene_131\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0395.mp4" "scene_132\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0113.mp4" "scene_132\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0395.mp4" "scene_133\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0114.mp4" "scene_133\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0395.mp4" "scene_134\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0115.mp4" "scene_134\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0396.mp4" "scene_135\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0112.mp4" "scene_135\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0396.mp4" "scene_136\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0113.mp4" "scene_136\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0396.mp4" "scene_137\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0114.mp4" "scene_137\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0396.mp4" "scene_138\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0115.mp4" "scene_138\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0397.mp4" "scene_139\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0003.mp4" "scene_139\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0397.mp4" "scene_140\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0004.mp4" "scene_140\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0397.mp4" "scene_141\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0005.mp4" "scene_141\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0397.mp4" "scene_142\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0006.mp4" "scene_142\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0398.mp4" "scene_143\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0003.mp4" "scene_143\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0398.mp4" "scene_144\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0004.mp4" "scene_144\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0398.mp4" "scene_145\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0005.mp4" "scene_145\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0398.mp4" "scene_146\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0006.mp4" "scene_146\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0399.mp4" "scene_147\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0003.mp4" "scene_147\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0399.mp4" "scene_148\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0004.mp4" "scene_148\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0399.mp4" "scene_149\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0005.mp4" "scene_149\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0399.mp4" "scene_150\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0006.mp4" "scene_150\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0400.mp4" "scene_151\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0003.mp4" "scene_151\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0400.mp4" "scene_152\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0004.mp4" "scene_152\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0400.mp4" "scene_153\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0005.mp4" "scene_153\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0400.mp4" "scene_154\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0006.mp4" "scene_154\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0401.mp4" "scene_155\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0005.mp4" "scene_155\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0401.mp4" "scene_156\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0006.mp4" "scene_156\"
>   MOVE ".\1\YDXJ0410.mp4" "scene_157\"
>   MOVE ".\2\YDXJ0015.mp4" "scene_157\"

And all of the folders created. Which is right. If I remove ECHO(

I get the first files moved and the error "The system cannot find the drive specified." on the next line. After this I set the source directory (I'm running at a bat)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\example\"
SET /a COUNT=0

if NOT ["%errorlevel%"]==["0"] pause

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

for %%i in (".\1\*.mp4") do (
 for %%a in (".\2\*.mp4") do (
 CALL :cmpdt "%%~ti" "%%~ta"
  IF DEFINED samedt (
   IF /i "%%~nxi"=="%%~nxa" (ECHO filename match "%%a" - no action taken
   ) ELSE (
    SET /a COUNT+=1
    md "scene_!COUNT!"
    MOVE "%%i" "scene_!COUNT!\"
    MOVE "%%a" "scene_!COUNT!\"
   )
  )
 ) 
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF

:: compare date and time %1 to %2. Set samedt=Y if within n secs (assume date same)
:cmpdt
IF "%~1"=="%~2" SET "samedt=Y"&GOTO :EOF
SET "samedt="
:: some temp variables ($1,$2)
SET "$1=%~1"
SET "$2=%~2"
:: compare dates - first 10 characters - if neq, not a match
IF "%$1:~0,10%" neq "%$2:~0,10%" GOTO :EOF
:: convert from "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm ?m" to "hhmm?" - 12:xx to 00:xx
IF "%$1:~11,2%"=="12" (SET "$1=00%$1:~14,2%%$1:~17,1%") ELSE (SET "$1=%$1:~11,2%%$1:~14,2%%$1:~17,1%")
IF "%$2:~11,2%"=="12" (SET "$2=00%$2:~14,2%%$2:~17,1%") ELSE (SET "$2=%$2:~11,2%%$2:~14,2%%$2:~17,1%")
:: Now covert hh to minutes and compensate for am/pm. 
:: add 100 to hh,mm by prefixing `1` then subtracting 100 to overcome octal maths
IF /i "%$1:~-1%"=="A" (SET /a $1=(1%$1:~0,2% - 100^)*60+1%$1:~2,2%-100
 ) ELSE (
  SET /a $1=(1%$1:~0,2% - 100 + 12^)*60+1%$1:~2,2%-100
)
IF /i "%$2:~-1%"=="A" (SET /a $2=(1%$2:~0,2% - 100^)*60+1%$2:~2,2%-100
 ) ELSE (
  SET /a $2=(1%$2:~0,2% - 100 + 12^)*60+1%$2:~2,2%-100
)
:: Now have minutes-since-midnight in $1,$2. Date is the same, $1 neq $2
:: allow difference of 3 minutes
SET /a diff=3
SET /a $1=$1+diff
SET /a diff=2*diff
:cmpl
IF %$1%==%$2% SET "samedt=Y"
IF %diff%==0 GOTO :EOF 
SET /a diff-=1
SET /a $1-=1
GOTO cmpl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET /a COUNT=0

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

for %%i in (".\1\*.mp4") do (
 for %%a in (".\2\*.mp4") do (
  IF "%%~ti"=="%%~ta" (
   IF /i "%%~nxi"=="%%~nxa" (ECHO filename match "%%a" - no action taken
   ) ELSE (
    SET /a COUNT+=1
    md "scene_!COUNT!"
    ECHO(MOVE "%%i" "scene_!COUNT!\"
    ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "scene_!COUNT!\"
   )
  )
 )
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Note that in the Windows world, `\` is a directory-separator and `/` is a switch-indicator. Windows often, but not always, makes the translation. Best to use the correct form.

Using `delayedexpansion`, the run-time value of a variable is accessed by `!var!`. `%var%` is always the parse-time value

OTT, I've added an extra test - if the filenames match, no `move` is attempted and a report line generated.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET /a COUNT=0

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

for %%i in (".\1\*.mp4") do (
 for %%a in (".\2\*.mp4") do (
 CALL :cmpdt "%%~ti" "%%~ta"
  IF DEFINED samedt (
   IF /i "%%~nxi"=="%%~nxa" (ECHO filename match "%%a" - no action taken
   ) ELSE (
    SET /a COUNT+=1
    md "scene_!COUNT!"
    ECHO(MOVE "%%i" "scene_!COUNT!\"
    ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "scene_!COUNT!\"
   )
  )
 )
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF

:: compare date and time %1 to %2. Set samedt=Y if within n secs (assume date same)
:cmpdt
IF "%~1"=="%~2" SET "samedt=Y"&GOTO :EOF
SET "samedt="
:: some temp variables ($1,$2)
SET "$1=%~1"
SET "$2=%~2"
:: compare dates - first 10 characters - if neq, not a match
IF "%$1:~0,10%" neq "%$2:~0,10%" GOTO :EOF
:: convert from "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm ?m" to "hhmm?" - 12:xx to 00:xx
IF "%$1:~11,2%"=="12" (SET "$1=00%$1:~14,2%%$1:~17,1%") ELSE (SET "$1=%$1:~11,2%%$1:~14,2%%$1:~17,1%")
IF "%$2:~11,2%"=="12" (SET "$2=00%$2:~14,2%%$2:~17,1%") ELSE (SET "$2=%$2:~11,2%%$2:~14,2%%$2:~17,1%")
:: Now covert hh to minutes and compensate for am/pm. 
:: add 100 to hh,mm by prefixing `1` then subtracting 100 to overcome octal maths
IF /i "%$1:~-1%"=="A" (SET /a $1=(1%$1:~0,2% - 100^)*60+1%$1:~2,2%-100
 ) ELSE (
  SET /a $1=(1%$1:~0,2% - 100 + 12^)*60+1%$1:~2,2%-100
)
IF /i "%$2:~-1%"=="A" (SET /a $2=(1%$2:~0,2% - 100^)*60+1%$2:~2,2%-100
 ) ELSE (
  SET /a $2=(1%$2:~0,2% - 100 + 12^)*60+1%$2:~2,2%-100
)
:: Now have minutes-since-midnight in $1,$2. Date is the same, $1 neq $2
:: allow difference of 3 minutes
SET /a diff=3
SET /a $1=$1+diff
SET /a diff=2*diff
:cmpl
IF %$1%==%$2% SET "samedt=Y"
IF %diff%==0 GOTO :EOF 
SET /a diff-=1
SET /a $1-=1
GOTO cmpl
```

Revision to suit the "time difference" idea.

The subroutine `:cmpdt` compares that date and time of the two files in `date hh:mm ?M` format where `date` is 10 characters long.

If the date is not the same, then `samedt` is left "set" to *nothing* (ie not defined - the `if defined` test applies to the run-time value)

If the dte parts are the same, then the time part is manipulated to `hhmm?` where `12:xx AM` becomes `00xxA`, `01:xx AM` `01xxA` and so on.

This string is then manipulted again, calculating 60*hours+minutes for AM or 60*(hours+12)+minutes for PM. Batch treats leading `0` as octal, so `1` is strung before the 2-digit hour/minute and then 100 subtracted.

Result is minutes-since midnight. If required difference (diff) is 3 then add this to one and test against the other decrementing the result (diff*2+1) times. If any match, then set the 'samedt' flag.

Example :- `03:10 PM` becomes `0310P` and then 910 (((3+12)*60)+10) if the other time is say 907 (3 minutes earlier) and `diff` is `3` then add  to 910 ==> 913, compare to 907 and decrement. repeat 7 times (913, 912...908,907)

**Please note that this code applies a DIFF of 3 minutes - to show that it's general and you can set it to any value you prefer**

although - since the times delivered are in minutes, not seconds, the incidence of having two different times at all should be very low.

(complicated - could be done in other ways, but it will work. Batch can do a lot of things if you're sufficiently determined...)

Comment: However.. the directories are being created but no files are moved. Any way to easily debug this?

Comment: No I got too excited and didn't read it properly. You're a hero thanks so much!

Comment: A few of these files are out by 1 second. Is there anyway to add a check if a file date is plus or minus 1 second? i.e. can you do maths on "%%~ti"=="%%~ta".

Comment: Qualified yes. On my system, the filetime is in hh:mm (24-hr) format, so if your filetime according to `%%~t?` has a coarse measurement of 1 minute as has mine, the 1 second difference is only going to happen if the times are XX:59(:59) and xx+1:00(:00) - somewhat rarely. But it's possible - would need to know the time-format you are using. pop a `echo %%~ti" command into the outer loop to see...

Comment: 15/04/2016 03:10 PM is the timestamp of one file. It's possible the camera clocks aren't exactly syncronised etc, so even within plus or minus 1 minute would probably help.

Comment: Please note that the code imposes a 3-minute difference. To make it one, simply change the setting of `diff` in the subroutine from 3 to 1...

Comment: Man you're awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm just using this again and I've tried changing the echo(move to move, and it's only running the first 2 files. Is there anything else I need to change? i.e. i've tried removing the corresponding '(' but that isn't helping

Comment: `echo(` is a single command. It's exploiting a characteristic of `echo`  where the character following the `o` has different effects. Space is the normal and documented syntax, but `\/,(` all work (as do others) the same as `echo[space]` - except that if `var` is empty, `echo %var%`will produce `echo is on/off` whereas `echo(%var%` produces a new line, so it's safe if the thing to be printed is empty. The `(` in `echo(` plays no part in the parenthesis-management. Simply replace `echo(` with *nothing* and the `move` should be actiavted. With the `echo(` in place, the `move` command is `echo`ed

Comment: Thanks I've got that working. It's just only working on the first 2 files. Any suggestions for getting it working across the whole lot?

Comment: @user5839 seems odd.  You appear to be saying that with `echo(move` in place, you get more than 2 lines of report, but changing `echo(move` to simply `move` moves two files then stops. Could you edit your question to include some sample output, eg. report with say a half-dozen lines that stops after moving two? It's not easy to reproduce your exact circumstances (and sorry I don't hang around here much any more - has to wait until I trip over the site in a search...)